# Google OR-Tools - get intermediate value of decision variable as input for constraint

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I am solving a problem in which one of my decision variables is O, or the order of sequence. This takes a form like 3-1-2-0, meaning fourth product (third index) is scheduled first, then the second product etc.

I need the particular element of O, e.g. 3, as input for looking up an upperbound for a subsequent constraint. Namely, my decision variable y[n, r, d] depends on the produced sequence, since for each planned product 'n', it needs to allocate something. This allocation forms the costs and thus objective function of the model

**Problem**
I have thus been unable to acces the elements of O before solving the entire model. Rather, after deciding on a sequence, I need to extract elements from O to determine its costs. Below is my code, where i highlighted where I need the element of O. See in particular 'Raw constraint 1' and 'Raw constraint 2'.

```
        solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('CP-SAT')
        model = cp_model.CpModel()
        
        # initialize emtpy dictionairies for later decision variables
        x = {}
        p = {}
        o = {}
        z = {}
        y = {}
        s = {}
        h = {}
        
        # whether product i is followed by j
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                x[i, j] = model.NewIntVar(0, 1, f'transition_{i}_{j}')
                
                
        # axuiliary variable to maintain position integrity
        # p[i] variables denote the position of a planned product (e.g. 3rd, 1st, 2nd)
        # o[i] variables denote the actual sequence, so e.g. 2 - 3 - 1
        for i in range(N):
            p[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, N-1, f'position_{i}')
            o[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, N-1, f'sequence_{i}')

        # z[i][j] ensures o[i] maintains the sequence as determined in p[i]
        # see excel example
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                z[i, j] = model.NewIntVar(-N, N, f'auxiliary_{i}_{j}')

        # y is the allocation of raw materials for planned product n
        # s and h are custom variables for later determining the costs
        for n in range(N):
            for r in range(R):
                for d in range(D):
                    y[n, r, d] = model.NewIntVar(0, 1, f'allocation_{i}_{r}_{d}')
                    s[n, r, d] = model.NewIntVar(0, 1, f'softs_{i}_{r}_{d}')
                    h[n, r, d] = model.NewIntVar(0, 1, f'hards_{i}_{r}_{d}')
```

```
costs = sum(1000 * h[n, r, d] + 1 * s[n, r, d] for n in range(N) for r in range(R) for d in range(D))

                    
        # set the objective as the total cost, goal is to minimize
        model.Minimize(costs)
        


        # scheduling constraint 1: each product has exactly one sucessor
        # we do not enforce this hard, since the last scheduled has no successor
        for i in range(N):
            model.Add(sum(x[i, j] for j in range(N)) <= 1)
    
        # constraint 2: each product is preceded by exactly one other
        # we do not enforce this hard, since the first one does not have a predecessor
        for j in range(N):
            model.Add(sum(x[i, j] for i in range(N)) <= 1)
            
            
        # scheduling constraint 3: the total number of movements is at max N-1
        # this means every product is selected once, except the start product
        model.Add(sum(x[i, j] for i in range(N) for j in range(N)) == N - 1)
        
        
        
        # scheduling constraint 4: avoid circular dependencies, i.e. 1 -> 2 -> 1 is not allowed
        # this means a sequence cannot loop back to a previously visited point
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                    model.Add(x[i, j] + x[j, i] <= 1)
                    
                
                                       
        # scheduling constraint 5: The start product has no predecessor
        model.Add(sum(x[i, zero_j] for i in range(N)) == 0)  

        # scheduling constraint 6: The start product must have a successor
        model.Add(sum(x[zero_j, j] for j in range(N)) == 1)  
                    
        
        # scheduling constraint 7: positional constraint
        # if i is in the sequence, its position must be smaller than j if j is after i
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                    model.Add(p[i] + 1 <= p[j] + M * (1 - x[i, j]))
                    
            
                    
        # scheduling constraint 8: positional constraint
        # the sum of assigned positions should be equal to the sum of range N i.e. each position is present once
        model.Add(sum(p[i] for i in range(N)) == sum_n)
        
        
        # scheduling onstraint 9: Sum of z values
        # this constraint aims to derive decision variable o from decision variable p
        for i in range(N):
            model.Add(sum(j * z[i, j] for j in range(N)) == p[i])
```

```
        # scheduling constraint 8: positional constraint
        # the sum of assigned positions should be equal to the sum of range N i.e. each position is present once
        model.Add(sum(p[i] for i in range(N)) == sum_n)
        
        
        # scheduling onstraint 9: Sum of z values
        # this constraint aims to derive decision variable o from decision variable p
        for i in range(N):
            model.Add(sum(j * z[i, j] for j in range(N)) == p[i])  

            for j in range(N):
                model.Add(z[i, j] <= 1)  
                model.Add(z[i, j] >= 0) 

        # scheduling constraint 10: 
        # this constraint ensures that only '1's can be placed in matrix z[i][j], such that o[i] becomes exact sequence
        for i in range(N):
            model.Add(sum(z[i, j] for j in range(N)) == 1)  

        # scheduling constraint 12: Sum of z values in each column is 1
        # this constraint ensures that only '1's can be placed in matrix z[i][j], such that o[i] becomes exact sequence
        for j in range(N):
            model.Add(sum(z[i, j] for i in range(N)) == 1)  

        # schedling constraint 13: Calculation of o[j]
        # here, we set the actual production order with index of product
        for j in range(N):

        # raw constraint 1: a raw material must be scheduled if needed
        # this means the sum of a row (raw material) must be equal to 1 (raw material need) and 0 otherwise
        for n in range(N):
            for r in range(R):
                #idx = o[n].Value
                **idx = solver.Value(o[n])** # intermediate value of O needed here to index an external matrix
                model.Add(sum(y[n,r,d] for d in range(D))) == self.b_need_raw[idxs[idx]][i]
                
        
        # raw constraint 2: a raw material can only be scheduled on where it is allowed
        # this information is stored in the 'matrix'
        for n in range(N):
            for r in range(R):
                for d in range(D):
                    **idx = solver.Value(o[n])**  intermediate value of O needed here to index an external matrix
                    
# custom constraints to determine costs 's' and 'h'


for n in range(N-1):
       for d in range(D):
                
                col_sum = sum(y[n,r,d] for r in range(R))  
                
                for r in range(R):  
                    model.Add(s[n,r,d] >= (y[n,r,d] - y[n+1,r,d])*-1 - col_sum)
                    model.add(s[n,r,d] >= 0)

        for n in range(N-1):
            for d in range(D):
                
                col_sum = sum(y[n,r,d] for r in range(R))  
                
                for r in range(r):  
                    model.Add(h[n,r,d] >= (y[n+1,r,d]- y[n,r,d]) - (1-col_sum))
                    model.Add(h[n,r,d] >= 0)
```

As can be inferred, the costs, determined by h[n,r,d] and s[r,n,d], which depend on y[n,r,d], which is constraint by a value from an external matrix which is index by o[n]. However, o[n] often cannot be accessed before solving the model, yielding 'None'

I tried implementing callback methods to no avail. I need to both determine O and y[n,r,d] into a single solver. I am exclusively looking at free-to-use solvers first, although i believe Gurobi does support these kind of features.

Comment: Why do create create a pywraplp solver ?

Comment: clips of incomplete code means lots of undefined variables !!!  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)